# Get Ionic Framework to show content in iPhone/Android environment(Mobile Browser Simulator)

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get this sample for Ionic Framework Beta 6 working in IBM Worklight.

I have bootstrap Angular.js and have it working fine with Worklight. When I run/build the project on a browser (Firefox/Chrome). The sample below is working and the content is showing on the screen.

However, when I create an iPhone environment and run in the Mobile Browser Simulator or on the device, the page is blank.

Does anyone know what could cause the blank page, even though the content displayed fine in a regular browser?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionic.css">
  <script src="js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script>
      window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ui-view></div>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**menu.html**

```
   <ion-side-menus>

    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>Item</ion-item>
          <ion-item>Item</ion-item>
          <ion-item>Item</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu-content> 

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
        <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
       <ion-list>
          <ion-item>Item</ion-item>
          <ion-item>Item</ion-item>
          <ion-item>Item</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>

  </ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this related question: [IBM Worklight v6.1.0.1 : Error when using Ionic Framework with Worklight and run on IOS environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821136/ibm-worklight-v6-1-0-1-error-when-using-ionic-framework-with-worklight-and-run)
You can test in the iOS Simulator.

Here is a blog post about Worklight and Ionic with a full sample project: http://mobileroly.blogspot.co.il/2014/04/using-angular-js-and-ionic-on-ibm.html

Comment: I applied the changes suggested in the link for "IBM Worklight v6.1.0.1 : Error when using Ionic Framework with Worklight and run on IOS environment" but all it displays is a cut off header bar, with no list. Something else seems to be blocking the content. I'm not sure what else is needed?

Comment: You need to add padding to whichever element holds your content. As I said, ionic is not officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem whereby the list of accounts in the accounts page is not shown in the Mobile Browser Simulator. I was using Worklight Studio 6.2.... but since I upgraded to this build 6.2.0.00-20140801-1709, this problem was resolved.